# Dash/hyphen sign resets path in FTP#list in ruby

Tags: ruby, directory, ftp

I have a strange problem with ruby's `FTP#list` method. When I'm connected to the server and I want to list recursively all paths I encounter a path reset when a path contains the dash sign.
Structure:

```
/dir1/dir2/file
/dir1/dir3/file
/dir1/dir-4/file
```

When I try to list the dir with the dash:

```
> ftp.list('/dir1/dir-4/') =>
=> /dir1/dir2/file
=> /dir1/dir3/file
=> /dir1/dir-4/file
```

instead of:

```
=> /dir1/dir-4/file
```

This problem does not occur for non-dashed dir names.
I wonder if it's possible to escape a listed dir somehow. I tried multiple combinations and it ended up with empty results.
I would appreciate any form of help.

Comment: FTP cannot actually list files diretly, it's dependent on parsing the output of a remote `ls` command, which means this could be some kind of parsing error. Considering it's 2020, don't you have a better option like SCP?

Comment: I'm forced to work with it due to vendor limitations.

Comment: Sorry you have to work with vendors from the 20th century. I'm not sure if there's an easy fix here other than renaming the directory or perhaps looking more closely at the FTP module's source.

Comment: What about passing a block to `list` and use regex do get only files in paths that have a dash in it? If for `FTP` you mean `Net::FTP` from Std-lib that should be possible.